# Image caching and loading in Linear layout

Tags: android

I am searching for fast solution how to cash images.

I found many done this in loading in ListView images.

However i need to load images into ImageButton which is subview of Linear layout.

Maybe someone saw this implemented or could give me some tips how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: u got images from links or not

Comment: have store it in cash means sd card or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use your applications cache directory to cache your images. Use `Context's` `getCacheDir()` api to get your cache directory path.